# Spring MVC 3 Ambiguous Mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to setup a convention based mapping for spring, but it always gives me the **ambiguous mapping** error.
Here is my controller class:

```
package com.bsci.tracker.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping
    public void index(){}

    @RequestMapping
    public void home(){}
}
```

and here is my xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bsci.tracker.mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

*Also, I don't want to provide explicit request mapping on my controller methods, I want them to get called by the method names automatically.*

Answer (score 3):

That's true because you have two  `@RequestMapping` mapping mapped to the same default path, which if I rememebr correctly is "/".

You need to do the following:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/yourmapping1",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void index(){}

    @RequestMapping(value="/yourmapping2",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void home(){}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: [The RequestMapping javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value%28%29) states that if there are multiple RequestMappings with default value then the method name is used.  You shouldn't need to do this, the method names imply subdirs `/index` and `/home` respectively.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to have. I don't wanna provide explicit mapping. I want it to go by the method names. Am I missing something in the comfiguration?

Comment: @krock hey my question still remains unanswered. The thing is that I don't wanna provide specific mapping but want spring to go by method names. How to go about that??